# The use of the noun "will" in context

Tags: word-usage

Tell me please if I used the word *will* correctly in the following dialogue.

> Person 1: Can I turn off the music?
>
> Person 2: Sure, but why?
>
> Personv1: That is not my **will**. The old man doesn't like it.

I feel this use of the word *will* might be correct, but too formal. If I am right, what is the informal way to say it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your usage is not idiomatic. Although it's correct, it sounds theatrical or as if it comes from some classical text.

To say: **It's my will** has an old-fashioned ring. Nowadays people would say: **It's what I want/desire/would like** or similar.

So, the popular choices might be:

> It's not what I want/desire

or

> I don't want it off; it's the old man...

or

> > It's not I/me that wants it off; it's the old man...

(The use of **I** is more correct; the use of **me** is more popular)

The expression **my will** is more often reserved for the formal legal testament declaring how an estate will be divided after a person's death.

Comment: If you want a noun, I'd say _That is not my preference_. This may be a BrE usage.

Answer (score 1):

That is not idiomatic English. Today you'd say:

It's not my wish.

It's not what I want.

It's not me wanting it.

It's not me that wants it.